# Remove an event function that passes parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, function, events

I'm passing some parameters everytime i click a movieclip, and I'm not realising how to remove it

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunct(1,1));
```

I thought this could work, but it isn't working...

```
my_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunct)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. Rather what is not working that you think should work. BTW, 'someFunct(1,1)' in addEventListener and 'someFunct' in removeEventListener seems fishy!!

Comment: No error at all, it just doesn't remove the listener...

Answer (score 1):

Try stopImmidiatePropagation(); It will stop all evnts

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the syntax you posted is actually working, unless someFunct itself returns a function that is the actual event listener (the exception is that Flex has some stuff under the hood that will create the illusion that you can do this). In any case, what you have is more or less an anonymous function if this is remotely working as posted.

The only place you can remove an anonymous function is inside the listener. However, the listener would have to have a more conventional event listener signature (have a single parameter that is the event). Assuming that somewhere in your code there's somebody that looks like that:

```
protected function someFunct(param1:int, param2:int):void {
    return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
        trace('in listener', param1, param2);
    }

}
```

If you're using Flex, I don't think there's a way to get at where the anonymous function is created to allow the listener to be removed. For more on how this stuff works, try reading [this](http://www.developria.com/2010/12/functional-actionscript-part-1.html).

Comment: ofc it returns a function... but i'm lookin for a way to remove that listener without a lot of work D:

Comment: You'll need to use a named function instead of an anonymous function if you want to remove it outside of the listener itself. Or you can destroy my_mc and remove it from the stage. When it is garbage collected, the closure will be as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and figured out how to accomplish this. Below is a test .as main file, just make it the main document class of a new .fla file and run it. You can clearly see it working. As for your exaple, you can just replace this.stage with your movieclip.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public function Main() {
        graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunct(1, 1));
    }
    private function someFunct(p1:int, p2:int):Function {
        return someFunct2
    }
    private function someFunct2(event:MouseEvent):void {
        graphics.drawCircle(this.stage.mouseX, this.stage.mouseY, 50);
        this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunct2)
    }
}
}
```

If this has not answered your question, please comment back, or edit your question and clarify what you really want. Thank You